# URL name change in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am building my first website and trying to change URL names in htaccess so e.g. https://youmedigital.com/index.html will display as https://youmedigital.com/home or https://youmedigital.com/about.html#mystory will display as https://youmedigital.com/mystory.
I have tried multiple codes and none of them seem to work for me - I don't know how to write php and I am relying on whatever I find online.

Most of the advises found on web led me to use the below but it's not working.

```
RewriteRule   ^skills/?$   skills.html  [NC]
```

The only code that worked for me (found on stackoverflow) was the one below however it only removes html from all my url's. I was advised to replace html with php to remove php extension but then my contact form stops working.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I still need a solution to replace e.g https://youmedigital.com/about.html#mystory  with https://youmedigital.com/mystory

I would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You cannot rewrite URL anchors in the server side (#mystory), since they are handled on the client side and _not_ part of the request URL.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "but it's not working"? Are we meant to guess?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot the `RewriteEngine on`? Or the rewriting module is not loaded into your http server? Or you did not enable the interpretation of that dynaqmic configuration file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply arkascha. By saying it's not working I mean that my website is still displaying https://youmedigital.com/skills.html instead of https://youmedigital.com/skills when i use this simple rewriting rule: RewriteRule   ^skills/?$   skills.html  [NC]. I have used RewriteEngine on. Thanks for clarifying regarding (#mystory).

Comment: So what about the other points I addressed? _Is_ the rewriting module loaded at all into your http server? Did you check? How? _Did_ you enable the interpretation of that dynamic configuration file? How did you do that? Or check that? If you cannot answer that, then I suggest that you refer to the official documentation. As with most OpenSource projects the documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you, I will review the documentation to see where I'm making an error.

Answer (score 0):

index.html -> home

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home index.html
```

about.html#mystory -> mystory

- no way to do that

Comment: Thank you however this one is not working for me either